# How to adjust scale to occupy more data in d3js

Tags: d3.js

I'm drawing a scatter plot with d3js. Using a simple linear scale with 1,2,3,4,5. This creates equal space like:

`1     2      3       4      5`

problem is, I have more data points between 2 and 3, 3 and 4. less data points between 1 and 2, 4 and 5. Is it possible to configure the scale to look like:

`1 2      3                4 5`

or instead of linear scale I should try some other scales? Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

First, a word of warning: distorting a scale (depending on the data you want to visualize) can maybe have "undesired" effects.

If you want to go ahead, I quickly set up a fiddle to show a possible way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1gmffpv8/)

Basically, I am using custom domain/ranges to get the desired effect:

```
var x2 = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .range([0, 20, 80, 170, 200]);
```

Does that help?

Comment: You have shown the way to plot the axis. How do I get the location of actual data using this scale?

Comment: just use the scale, like: `x2(1)` (should return 0), or `x2(1.5)` (should yield 10). Just add `console.log(x2(3)` to try it in the fiddle. OK like this?